# Use mysql EXISTS with a const string

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, sql-in

can u help me understand to difference between `EXISTS` and `IN` using mysql ?.
in my application i am using `IN` in my queries,
since i am using memcached to store the IN values,
so i find IN more faster the EXISTS,
for example :

```
String my_chached_string = Memecached.get('somekey')
"SELECT * FROM Table t WHERE t.fromId IN (" + my_chached_string + ")"
```

my question, is there a way to use EXISTS the same way, with constant values ?

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some common coding patterns:

```
WHERE col = 'string'
WHERE col IN ('string') -- same as above
WHERE col IN ('string1', 'string2')
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ... )
```

The EXISTS one is really solving a different situation; I don't understand why you threw it in.  Even if there were an equivalent EXISTS pattern, it would necessarily be less efficient.

This pattern in terribly inefficient:

```
WHERE col IN ( SELECT ... )
```

It can often be made more efficient by transforming into a JOIN.

Comment: i know that EXIST evaluate single true or false but IN compare multiple value, so exists is a bit better, in my case i have to make two exists queries to run my query, this is way i chose IN with PREFETCHED values (and its running faster)! i was just wondering if i can use EXISTS with PREFETCHED values, thank you

Comment: EXISTS with prefetched values will not be faster than IN with prefetched values.  EXISTS without prefetching will beat IN.  If your timings found otherwise, then run them a second time -- caching could have confused the timings.

Comment: thanks rick, i guess my EXISTS queries are not so simple,
i changed lots of queries from EXISTS to IN with prefetched values and my application performance was very imporoved